# Finding the limit by using Maclaurin series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac {x\cdot \sin x}{1-\cos(2x)} $$

I'm supposed to find the limit by using the terms, and figuring out $ x\times \sin x$ is easy enough, just multiply $\sin x$ with $x$, but when it's divided by $1-\cos(2x)$, I'm really lost. I can and have calculated what the first 5 terms of $1-\cos(2x)$ is, but I have no idea what I do with those two to get one series, so I can get the limit. If WolframAlpha isn't lying to me, the limit should be $\frac{1}{2}$.

From all my lecturer has written, I can't see anywhere that it is mentioned how I divide power series of any kind in the notes he wrote. Now, I'm studying over the internet, so I just follow the lectures online, and don't have any proper help around me, so hence, I'm asking here, for the second time in 24hrs.

So where do I go from having the first 5 terms of the Maclaurin series of $ x\times \sin x$ and $1-\cos(2x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\cos 2x = 1 - \frac12 (2x)^2 + \frac1{24} (2x)^4 + \dots,$ so $1 - \cos 2x = 2 x^2 - \frac{2}{3} x^4 + \dots$ and $x \sin x = x^2 - \frac16 x^4 + \dots.$ Thus $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \sin x}{1 - \cos 2x} = \frac{x^2 - \frac16 x^4 + \dots}{2 x^2 - \frac23 x^4 + \dots} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \frac16 x^2 + \dots}{2 - \frac23 x^2 + \dots} = \frac12$ simply by evaluating the limits of the numerator and denominator. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Wait, so I find the limit of each of them separately, and then divide the upper by the lower limit, and thats my answer?! Sounds too easy lol! And I tried to actually divide them, and holy s**t, that was a load of unnecessary work! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well, yeah, you just divide by $x^2$ and the resulting quantities are then convergent, so it is valid to compute the limit this way. What we have done is basically eliminating the apparent singularity at $0$ (apparent because as you have seen, this is not actually a singularity). You're most welcome, dear. :)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\sin(x)=x+x\epsilon(x)$$

$$1-\cos(2x)=2\sin^2(x)$$

$$\frac{x\sin(x)}{1-\cos(2x)}=\frac{x}{2\sin(x)}$$
$$=\frac 12\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$$

$$=\frac 12\frac{1}{1+\epsilon(x)}$$
the limit is $ 0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use *Taylor-Young's formula* at order $2$:
$$\cos u=1-\frac{u^2}2+o(u^2),$$
and substitute $2x$ to $u$.